# Idea with php logic using operators

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and find it very hard to explain.

I have a PHP navigation script with 5 categories and two variables relevant to my question:

```
$catname = 'used-cars'; // the same value for all categories

$currentpage; // pages 1 to 5 

index.php of my site has $currentpage == '1'
```

The issue is that I need a logic that will say:

If $catname IS NOT 'used-cars', do something, BUT, IF $currentpage is equal to 1, even if $catname is 'used-cats' do it anyway

I am thinking of something like this:

```
if($catname != 'used-cars' && !($currentpage > '1')):

endif;
```

Hope you can help!

Comment: You mean for both conditions to be `used-cars`, correct? In your explanation you have `used-cats`, which makes for another situation entirely.  (lots of used cats need homes-- contact your local Humane Society!)

Comment: Lol Michael, will do, will do:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is merely a single `or` condition.  On the right side, `$currentpage === 1` will evaluate to TRUE without regard to the value of `$catname`.  If either part of the condition is TRUE, you'll enter the `if ()` block to execute your code there.

```
if ($catname !== "used-cars" || $currentpage === 1) {
  // do your thing

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just:

```
if (strcmp($catname, 'used-cars') != 0 || $currentpage == 1)
```

(Careful with the string comparison.)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could declare it as a boolean first:

```
$proceed = false;

if($catname != 'used-cars')
    $proceed = true;

if($currentpage == 1)
    $proceed = true;

if($proceed){
    // whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$doflag = 0;
if($catname != 'used-cars') 
{
  $doflag = 1;
} else if($currentpage == 1) {
  $doflag = 1;
}

if($doflag == 1) {
  //do something
}
```

Basically instead of trying to do everything with the block, use the block to set a flag and use the flag to do something.